# Crop and rotate image on server using guillotine library

Tags: php, gd, jquery-guillotine

I am using guillotine script and on client side i am able to rotate and scale image. i get the data object like below

```
{scale: 1, angle: 0, x: 0, y: 67, w: 400, h:300 }
```

I know how  a server side script in php can  rotate an image.

```
$rotate          = imagerotate( $image_source, $degrees, 0 );
```

using some thing like this. how can i crop or scale an image. i just want to use gd library.

Thanks